# Where do I find currently discussed proposals to the C++ standard

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

There's always several things that are proposed to be included to the next [c++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents)

- How do I find a list of them?
- Ho do I find some specific proposal I've heard of (by name, for example Ranges TS or Concurency TS)
- If I have some document how do I know if it is a current version?

Comment: You'll find relevant info here: https://isocpp.org/std

Comment: Don't really see how is it different in being on/off-topic from linked question which is in faq, but ok

Comment: @RiaD I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the consensus on the linked question is that it's technically off-topic, too, but both old enough that it was probably around before "on-topic" was hammered out, and useful enough to C & C++ programmers that it was effectively grandfathered in and allowed to stay.

Comment: That said, this question looks like it would be useful as an addendum to it, so perhaps the linked question should be amended to also link to C & C++ proposals.

Comment: @RiaD - If you happen to get a few hundred upvotes before decided to be off-topic, you might get special dispensation from the moderators. Otherwise not.