# c++ proposal for new mathematical special functions

Tags: c++, std

`C++17` introduced a few "mathematical special functions" like Bessel functions and different types of polynomials in `<cmath>`.
Does someone know if there is any proposal to add new functions to the standard (like hypergeometric functions)? Is there any place where new proposals are collected in order to make it easy for us to search for a particular proposal?

Comment: You can follow to public mailing lists https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/

Comment: *"Is there any place where new proposals"* Dupe: [Where do I find currently discussed proposals to the C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461794/where-do-i-find-currently-discussed-proposals-to-the-c-standard)